# Good resources on how to write Emacs modes?

Tags: emacs

Can anyone recommend a good resource for getting started on writing Emacs modes?  Specifically, I'm looking at what it would take to write a syntax-highlighting and indentation mode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ModeTutorial

Answer (score 0):

I learnt how to do this from O'Reilly's [writing GNU emacs extensions](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565922617.do).